# question about the transformation of a distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have a question about the transformation of pdf.

$f(y|x)\propto\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}{[\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^2+\beta]^{(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}}\propto[\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\beta}+1]^{-(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}$

Does anyone could help me on how the right-hand side of the equation comes from the left-hand side of equation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That $\beta$ seems to have been outmultiplied. What do you know about Gamma functions?

Comment: What do you mean "outmultiplied"? I just know some basic properties, like $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ and $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt(\pi)$, and the equation is a solution to an exercise, but I don't know how it comes from.

Comment: I mean $(\beta + x) = \beta (\frac{x}{\beta} +1)$

Comment: Ok, I see, but I have checked all the previous steps, and I think nothing wrong with them, but I don't know how this step comes from, thanks for your help, if you have any idea, please let me know.